# Can i travel to Canada with Italian 1951 Convention Travel Document

Tags: air-travel

I've got Italian 1951 convention travel document, can I  travel to Canada for visit

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Canadian government website that will lead you through the steps of discovering whether you need a visa to visit Canada, whether briefly in transit or for a more extended visit.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp)

You can enter your country of citizenship and all other information about your trip, and it will tell you if you need a visa, and what visa you need.

If you select **A refugee travelling with a document for non-citizens** and **refugee travelling with another travel document for non-citizens** it will inform you that you must apply for a visa.  [The instructions to do so are here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html)